# Set default value for slider in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I'm trying to set a default value for my slider, but for some reason the handle value is not equal to that of the slider. I tried setting it in the CreateFcn function and then calling it back in my main function, but for some reason it's not being saved in handles.

```
 set(gcbo,'Value',1)
 handles.fuel_slider1 = get(gcbo,'Value')*100
 assignin('base','handles',handles);
 guidata(hObject,handles);
```

neither assigning nor guidata will retain the handles value and I can't call it anywhere.

I basically need to set 6 sliders to 100% and have those values be available in handles. Currently it returns the actual handle 'code' value or whatever it's called (fuel_slider2: 720.0043)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `gcbo`. If you are developing your UI in GUIDE, you have access to all of the sliders through the `handles` struct. You have an access to the current slider/uicontrol as well.

For example:

```
    set(handles.fuel_slider,'Value',1);
    guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Comment: I just tried this but as soon as any callback is initiated, handles gets overwritten and the default value is not available anymore. I basically need the default value set for the sliders to actually be available, now they are NOT in handles as long as their respective callback is used.

EDIT:
I just realized that the value is actually set but the only way to get it is with get().. it's not directly available in handles. I guess i'll just implement this function